# Loss of Quality in UAV Imagery after building pyramids in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, imagery, image-pyramids

I am using arcgis 10.1 to plot and print maps with a background with UAV imagery. When I insert an image (Tiff format), it loses quality.

The program prompts me to create pyramids, once this is complete, the image loses quality. What causes this? Is there a parameter which can be used to retain the original image quality?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried displaying your data without having first generated a pyramid? If so, did it look as expected?

Comment: It's an image pyramid.  The purpose isn't to retain quality, it's to quickly render an approximate image at scales much larger than the original image.  You can override the default pyramid options, but you aren't going to retain high quality in a resampled postage stamp.